# Like used with parameter don't work correctly

Tags: t-sql

This script should only pick the rows with brickurl = 'http://www.bol.com/something'
But it returns nearly all 30 rows, even with totally other texts in it

```
DECLARE @urlpart nvarchar
set @urlpart='bol.com'
SET @urlpart = '%'+@urlpart + '%'

SELECT * FROM Brick
WHERE BrickUrl like @urlpart
```

written without parameter like this:

```
SELECT * FROM brick
WHERE BrickUrl like '%bol.com%'
```

returns the 6 rows containing bol.com correctly.

I can't figure out what the reason is, or what I do wrong, do you see it?

Comment: brick is spelt differently (brik) in the two cases.  is that just a typo?

Comment: If those are `NVARCHAR` strings, you should use an `N'` prefix: `set @urlpart = N'bol.com' / SET @urlpart = N'%' + @urlpart + N'%'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @urlpart nvarchar
set @urlpart='bol.com'
SET @urlpart = '%'+@urlpart + '%'
select @urlpart
```

Result:

```
(No column name)
%
```

and then you should try this instead

```
DECLARE @urlpart nvarchar(128)
set @urlpart='bol.com'
SET @urlpart = '%'+@urlpart + '%'
select @urlpart
```

Result;

```
(No column name)
%bol.com%
```

When not specifying the size of `nvarchar` you will get size 1.